# Represent same state with different actions based on an event/action

Tags: uml

I am designing a state diagram for my software. I want to represent the following scenario

The application is in state X
---> (state X)

It can have two events/actions, eg. action A and action B

If action A is performed, it goes into the same state X and again action A and
action B are available.

But, if action B is performed, it again goes into the same state X but now action A and action B are not available, instead two new actions, action C and action D
are available.

action C and action D both will again lead back to the same state X

How can I represent this ?

Comment: That does not look like the same state.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine#Hierarchically_nested_states

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to realize that the last action was A vs. B, that requires remembering something.

*In a state machine, **remembering something that happened in the past is done with separated states***!

So, you need to introduce separate states to remember whether the last action was A or B.

In state X you can accept A & B.  On A you stay in state X.  On B you switch to X', which can accept C & D, which take you back to X or X' (your choice).

X and X' are not the same state!

Just because the two or more states are very similar doesn't mean you can optimize them into a single state.  You are essentially [prematurely optimizing](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) your states.

Answer (score 0):

Well it sounds like you're saying this

[image]

but you want all that to be one state. That doesn't make sense, not because you can't have that be one state and change the available events/actions like you say, but because having just one state is meaningless. So let me add a state Y and a way to get to it and back.

[image]

Now this could be simplified down into one state machine rather then nesting one inside the other like you have me doing here to satisfy this tortured requirement. But nothing says you have to. If you do simplify then e becomes available in both x1 and x2 states. That violates your requirements.

So this solution gives you two state machines that satisfies them by explicitly making state x have nothing to do with a, b, c, or d. Similarly x has nothing to do with e and f. Just like in your requirements.